# SQL Query Transpose not returning negative numbers

Tags: sql, view, transpose, zero, negative-number

I have a table that I am transposing by using a database view (using SQL Server). This table has positive and negative values. All of the negative values are returned as zero. Any ideas on how I can correct this?

Example of my original table:

| Year | Peak | Value_A | Value_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016 | AM | 15.156546 | 51.265146 |
| 2018 | AM | -15.5998 | -14.1565 |
| 2028 | AM | 16.3216 | 18.5611 |
| 2016 | IP | -0.01656 | -0.0026554 |
| 2018 | IP | -0.00159 | -0.59874 |
| 2028 | IP | 1.98438 | 3.362498 |
| 2016 | PM | -5.65436 | 8.6951 |
| 2018 | PM | 2.2316 | 3.859117 |
| 2028 | PM | -3.99842 | -9.620148 |

The result of my transposed view:

| Peak | Value_A_2016 | Value_A_2018 | Value_A_2028 | Value_B_2016 | Value_B_2018 | Value_B_2028 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AM | 15.156546 | 0 | 16.3216 | 51.265146 | 0 | 18.5611 |
| IP | 0 | 0 | 1.98438 | 0 | 0 | 3.362498 |
| PM | 0 | 2.2316 | 0 | 8.6951 | 3.859117 | 0 |

This is the SQL script for the view:

```
SELECT Peak, MAX(CASE WHEN T .YEAR = 2016 THEN T .[Value_A] ELSE 0.00 END) AS Value_A_2016, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN T .YEAR = 2018 THEN T .[Value_A] ELSE 0.00 END) AS Value_A_2018, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN T .YEAR = 2028 THEN T .[Value_A] ELSE 0.00 END) AS Value_A_2028, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN T .YEAR = 2016 THEN T .[Value_B] ELSE 0.00 END) AS Value_B_2016, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN T .YEAR = 2018 THEN T .[Value_B] ELSE 0.00 END) AS Value_B_2018, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN T .YEAR = 2028 THEN T .[Value_B] ELSE 0.00 END) AS Value_B_2028
FROM gisadmin.Table_1 AS T
GROUP BY Peak
```

Thanks very much for any assistance with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MAX(CASE 
    WHEN T.YEAR = 2018 THEN T.[Value_A] 
    ELSE 0.00
END) AS Value_A_2018
```

The problem is with the `else` branch, which returns 0 on rows that do not match the year predicate. Obviously 0 is greater than any negative value, so this is what `MAX` returns, hence "masking" the actual value.

Instead, you can just remove the else branch ; unmatched rows yield null values, that `max` ignores.

You can still assign a default value of 0 to null columns *afterwards* with `coalesce()`, if that’s what you want:

```
COALESCE(
    MAX(CASE 
        WHEN T.YEAR = 2018 THEN T.[Value_A] 
    END),
    0
) AS Value_A_2018
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that 0.00 is bigger that -0.003

if you remove the else clause, so that there is a NULL returned, you can get all the umbers

```
SELECT Peak, MAX(CASE WHEN T .YEAR = 2016 THEN T .[Value_A] END) AS Value_A_2016, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN T .YEAR = 2018 THEN T .[Value_A] END) AS Value_A_2018, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN T .YEAR = 2028 THEN T .[Value_A] END) AS Value_A_2028, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN T .YEAR = 2016 THEN T .[Value_B] END) AS Value_B_2016, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN T .YEAR = 2018 THEN T .[Value_B] END) AS Value_B_2018, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN T .YEAR = 2028 THEN T .[Value_B] END) AS Value_B_2028
FROM Table_1 AS T
GROUP BY Peak
```

| Peak | Value_A_2016 | Value_A_2018 | Value_A_2028 | Value_B_2016 | Value_B_2018 | Value_B_2028 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AM | 15.1565 | -15.5998 | 16.3216 | 51.2651 | -14.1565 | 18.5611 |
| IP | -0.0166 | -0.0016 | 1.9844 | -0.0027 | -0.5987 | 3.3625 |
| PM | -5.6544 | 2.2316 | -3.9984 | 8.6951 | 3.8591 | -9.6201 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/za6urOye)